# How to split text rows into multiple rows given there are many spaces between texts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe with one column "text":

```
text
I love cakes    we should make them
Joe is very late            will there be photography?
you should wright code correctly  it is very important
```

I want to explode those rows in cases where there are 2 or more spaces between texts. So desired output is:

```
text
I love cakes    
we should make them
Joe is very late            
will there be photography?
you should wright code correctly  
it is very important
```

I know that I can do: `df["text"].apply(lambda x: x.split("  "))` but I don't want to specify in split each number of spaces (`df["text"].apply(lambda x: x.split("    ")), df["text"].apply(lambda x: x.split("       ")), df["text"].apply(lambda x: x.split("               ")), .....`. i want 2+ spaces condition. how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split by regex and than `explode` the column

```
df = df['text'].str.split(r'\s{2,}').explode().reset_index().drop("index", 1)
```

Output

```
                               text
0                      I love cakes
1               we should make them
2                  Joe is very late
3        will there be photography?
4  you should wright code correctly
5              it is very important
```